# En sql puedo se puede hacer esto? Sumar y restar

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo una duda ¿En sql server puedo hacer esto? Es decir quiero multiplicar el campo Restante_RotorQTY  por el campo Stack  y al resultado de esa multiplicacion restarle el campo InventarioRotor. Asi como lo tengo lo que me hace es que me multiplica el campo inventario rotor por el stack y le resta la cantidad pendiente.

No se que tengo mal. Cualquier informacion seria de gran ayuda. Estoy usando sql 2014.

```
DECLARE @CantidadSolicitada INT
    IF EXISTS (SELECT Cod_Reg FROM TBL_FS_SaldoRotor WITH (NOLOCK) WHERE Cod_Reg  = CAST(ltrim(rtrim(@Cod_Reg)) as uniqueidentifier ))
    BEGIN

        SET @CantidadSolicitada =  (SELECT Restante_RotorQTY * Stack - InventarioRotor FROM TBL_FS_SaldoRotor FS WITH (NOLOCK) 
        WHERE FS.Cod_Reg = CAST(ltrim(rtrim(@Cod_Reg)) as uniqueidentifier) AND FS.Lamina =  @lamina)
```

Comment: Es SQL Server cierto?

Comment: Si asi es. sql 2014

Comment: ponele parentesis a lo que queres hacer ;)

Comment: La prioridad de operadores indica que primero se hacen multiplicaciones y divisiones de izquierda a derecha y luego sumas y restas en el mismo sentido. Por lo tanto, deberias obtener el resultado esperado y no la situación que describes. Te recomiendo verificar bien los datos.

Comment: Si tenias razon Luis Cazares error de dedo. Verifique bien los datos. Ya me esta obteniendo el resultado correcto. Gracias!!